# C Library Compile Error

Tags: c, compiler-construction, makefile, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile the sorting library from http://www.yendor.com/programming/sort/

Direct Link to library: http://www.yendor.com/programming/sort/sort-all.tgz

When I run *make* the compiler says:

```
gcc -g -O -DCUTOFF=15 -c sorttest.c
In file included from sorttest.c:15:
sort.h:66: error: conflicting types for ‘heapsort’
/usr/include/stdlib.h:301: error: previous declaration of ‘heapsort’ was here
make: *** [sorttest.o] Error 1
```

Can someone help with this issue?

Comment: looks like two files try to define `heapsort`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frosty,

Well, the compiler is complaining that the type `heapsort` is already defined at line `301` in `/usr/include/stdlib.h` ... the traditional methods for dealing with these issues are :

- Use another name for the offending article in your code. One supposes that `myheapsort` should do nicely. (and yes you can modify `sort-all.tgz`, coz it's published under GNU GPL)
- supress stdlib's definition of `heapsort` using #def #ifndef (if you can't change your code).
- Scream, cry, curse, and wish that all `stdlib`s (at least) where created equal. Sigh.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks!, I used your advice and just changed the code to myheapsort.